# eslint missing under \node_modules\.bin

Tags: node.js, express, eslint

I have globaly installed **eslint** using npm : `npm install -g eslint`, then I setup a configuration file `eslint --init` by answering the questions as follow :

```
? How would you like to configure ESLint? Use a popular style guide
? Which style guide do you want to follow? Airbnb
? Do you use React? No
? What format do you want your config file to be in? JavaScript
```

I tried to run eslint on my app.js file `eslint app.js`It doesn't work

I tried to run it doing so : `node_modules\.bin\eslint app.js` but Ican't  eslint file under \node_modules.bin

- NPM Version `5.6.0`
- Node Version `8.10.0`

Comment: Having it installed globally, for sure won't appear in the node_modules of your project. Add it as a dev dependency in your project's `package.json`, thus your second try will work.

Comment: I'm following pluralsight course, He installed it globaly and it worked for him !!

Comment: Let us know how did you install eslint globally. Also, show the output of the following typed in your terminal: `which eslint`

Comment: >which eslint
/c/Users/open/AppData/Roaming/npm/eslint

Comment: Are you using a Windows platform? If so, you should add that info to the question. Also executing `eslint --debug app.js` should output any error happening if indeed eslint is properly installed and, at least, running.

Comment: I'v got this error Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-airbnb-base' after runing eslint --debug app.js (Yes i'm using windows platforme)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167477/discussion-between-dez-and-mdit).

Comment: if you're on osx or linux, you gotta sudo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing the error you have just mentioned after trying:

```
eslint --debug app.js
```

You need to globally install the eslint plugin import and the eslint airbnb config plugin.

```
npm -g install eslint-plugin-import eslint-config-airbnb-base
```

You need to install said plugin because in the `eslint --init` configuration you have selected the Airbnb style guide.